# How to remove instance or row with missing values in Python Script in Orange Data Mining?

Tags: orange

I want to  remove an instance or row with missing values.

It's so simple to do it by using *Impute widget*, but now I want to do it in *Python Script Widget*.

How do I do this?

Comment: Could you please show me how to use the Impute widget to remove rows with missing values? I've been playing with Select Rows but still out of luck. I know that I could remove rows with Preprocess widget. However, in my case, I only want to remove missing values when certain columns have missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in **Python Script** widget:

```py
import numpy as np

from Orange.preprocess import impute


drop_instances = impute.DropInstances()
var = in_data.domain.attributes[0]  # choose a variable you wanna check
mask = drop_instances(in_data, var)

out_data = in_data[[np.logical_not(mask)]]
```

If you need more information, you are welcome to comment a question below!

Comment: Can you please explain where you get the syntax from? I thought dropping missing values is just `df.dropna`.

Comment: @HuyTruong: Yes, when you are using ```pandas.DataFrame```.